# how to remove an element at a specified location from a list in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have a problem, I have a list containing integer elements, and I want to remove one element and return a list without that removed element...
Is there such a function in Kotlin that let me do that? or should I do it myself?
I tried to use the *filter* function, make a variable equals to the elements in the place I want to remove, and then keep the elements that don't equal to that one but it was not like I wanted because some
times it removes more than one element that equal to the one I want to remove, just like this :

...

```
for (i in 0 until array.size){
var removed = array[i] 
array.filter{ it != removed }
.
.
. }
```

I'm kind of new to Kotlin, so can anyone help me here :)?

Comment: Make sure you know the difference between Array and List. Array should rarely be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a collection that has the flexibility of removing elements from the middle, you should probably not use an array directly. Consider using lists instead (`List`, `MutableList`).

If you want to change (mutate) a list, you have to have a `MutableList` in the first place, then you can call `remove(element)` on it to remove the element equal to the one you passed:

```kotlin
val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
list.remove("c")
println(list) // prints [a, b, d]
```

You can also call `removeAt(index)` on it to remove an element at a specific index:

```kotlin
val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
list.removeAt(2) // 2 is the index of element "c"
println(list) // prints [a, b, d]
```

It is usually advised to avoid mutable data structures when performance is not an issue. For instance, you can return a new list instead of mutating the original list. In that case, you don't need a `MutableList` (use a plain `List`), and you can simply use the `minus` operator:

```kotlin
val list1 = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
val list2 = list1 - "c"
println(list2) // prints [a, b, d]
```

I don't think there is an existing function for index-based subtraction in a `List`, but you can use `filterIndexed` and compare the index with the one you want to remove:

```
val list1 = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
val list2 = list1.filterIndexed { i, _ -> i != 2 } // 2 is the index of element "c"
println(list2) // prints [a, b, d]
```

Comment: Just curious if the last approach with filterIndexed is computationally more complex.
It seems the difference with the others is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first occurrence of a given item from a list:

Your list must be mutable. If you have an unmutable list,
cast it to a mutable one or reassign it to a new variable.

```
val list : List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(list) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var output = list.toMutableList()
output.remove(3) // remove element 3
println(output) // prints [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: But you remove the 1st 3 from the list.
It doesn't answer the question of how to remove at certain position.